# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)

Tags: flutter, sha1

I am using google console for login with email. its works properly before I add my project to firebase.
I want to send notification to user so I added my project to firebase for notification and its work good. but the problem is when I login with google it gives this error "**PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)**".
I saw the SHA1 key in both the platform (google console and firebase) are different different SHA1 key for the same app. I tried to put same key in both the platform so its gives me error **"The request failed because the Android package name and fingerprint are already in use"**

Another problem is when i try to creat new SHA1 key so it will genrate same key asper last.
I am stuck in this problem please help me.

I am using real android device for testing.